# Why can't I call my struct Semaphore methods?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++17, mutex

I am trying to input lowercase char and to add it to in.buffer, the other thread should read from in.buffer and make it lowercase and send to out.buffer, and the last one should read from out.buffer and print it.

I am getting error: expected identifier before numeric constant Semaphore m_free(10);
error: invalid use of member function ‘Semaphore RingBuffer::m_free(int)’

Why is that?

Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

struct Semaphore 
{
    Semaphore() = default;
    Semaphore(int x) : m_s(x) {}
    
    void release() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mut);
        m_s += 1;
        m_cv.notify_one();
    }
    void acquire() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mut);
        m_cv.wait(lock, [this](){ return m_s != 0; });
        m_s -= 1;
    }
    
    private:
    int m_s = 0;
    std::mutex m_mut;
    std::condition_variable m_cv;
};

struct RingBuffer {
    void write(char x);
    char read();
    
    private:
    std::array<char, 10> m_buff;
    int m_w = 0;
    int m_r = 0;
    Semaphore m_free(10);
    Semaphore m_taken(0);
    std::mutex m_mut;
};

void RingBuffer::write(char x) {
    m_free.acquire();
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(m_mut);
        m_buff[m_w] = x;
        m_w = m_w % 10 == 0 ? 0 : m_w + 1;
    }
    m_taken.release();
}
char RingBuffer::read() {
    int res=-1;
    m_taken.acquire();
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(m_mut);
        res = m_buff[m_r];
        m_r = m_r % 10 == 0 ? 0 : m_r + 1;
    }
    m_free.release();
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    //RING_SIZE;
    RingBuffer in,out;
    std::thread threadin([&in](){
        //while(true){
        char ch;
        std::cin>>ch;
        in.write(ch);
        
            
        //}
    });
    std::thread threaddo([&in,&out](){
        char ch=in.read();
         ch=ch-32;
         out.write(ch);
        //}
    });
    std::thread threadout([&out](){
        //while(true){
        char ch=out.read();
        std::cout<<ch<<std::endl;
        //}
    });
    
    threadin.join();
    threaddo.join();
    threadout.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Semaphore m_free(10)` -> `Semaphore m_free{10}`

Comment: but why is that so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't "call" anything inside a `struct`. A `struct` contains *definitions* of its members, not code.

You can initialize a member in a [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor):

```
struct RingBuffer {
    Semaphore m_free;
    RingBuffer() : m_free(10) {} // constructor with a member-initializer-list
};
```

Or inline using a [default member initializer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization):

```
struct RingBuffer {
    Semaphore m_free {10};
};
```

Or

```
struct RingBuffer {
    Semaphore m_free = 10;
};
```

But there is no syntax to initialize a member using `()`.